# preg_replace matching but not replacing

Tags: php, regex

In the code below I'm trying to take some text and wrap a html achor around it:

```
$d = "hello, there, how, are, you";
$d = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]+/", "<a href='?word=$1'>$1</a>", $d);
```

It correctly identifies each word and replaces each one with the replacement text BUT it doesn't put the matched word into the string, it just leaves it blank.  I'm on PHP5.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to capture the matches:

```
$d = "hello, there, how, are, you";
$d = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z]+)/", "<a href='?word=$1'>$1</a>", $d);
//                  ^         ^ you forgot these ;-)
```

Comment: If you means he misses the `(` & `)` , why not put the `^` just under them?

Comment: @xdazz I did - why, is it not displaying right for you? It does for me in Chrome... Your edit displayed with them underneath the first `,` and the `d` of `word` for me... very odd. **EDIT** I have just been through and replaced every whitespace character with a space from my keyboard - does it look right now?

Comment: I'm also in Chrome, and is under `p` and `/` for me. Sorry for my edit before, maybe it's the problem of my browser.

Comment: @xdazz That is bizarre, I guess yours must be merging the leading whitespace into one. How very odd.

Comment: @xdazz Your Chrome is not displaying the `<pre>` in monospace font - it might be worth reporting this on meta, I'm pretty sure that shouldn't happen. Here's how it looks to me: http://i41.tinypic.com/3501nas.jpg

Answer (score 4):

```
$d = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z]+)/", "<a href='?word=$1'>$1</a>", $d);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no first sub pattern in your needle.  Either of these will work.  Note the parenthesis in the first one, which saves a capturing group.  In the second one we say $0, which means the whole match.

```php
preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z]+)/", "<a href='?word=$1'>$1</a>", $d);
preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]+/", "<a href='?word=$0'>$0</a>", $d);
```

Comment: No worries, I +1ed you anyway cos I knew what you meant ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have missed parenthesis:

```
$d = "hello, there, how, are, you";
$d = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z]+)/", "<a href='?word=$1'>$1</a>", $d);
```

There is a free to tool which helps to learn regex (most flavors, including JS). Download and enjoy http://www.radsoftware.com.au

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the paranthesis

```
$d = "hello, there, how, are, you";
$d = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z]+)/", "<a href='?word=$1'>$1</a>", $d);
```